# Xamarin Forms ignore Button binding from DataType on StackLayout

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have got the following xaml code:

```
            <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:Light">
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" FontSize="24" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" >
                        <Button Text="{Binding Enabled}" Command="{Binding ToggleLight}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Button>
                    </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
```

How do I exclude `Command="{Binding ToggleLight}"` on my Button form the `x:DataType="model:Light"` defined on my StackLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [binding-path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-path).

1. Define "x:Name" outside the StackLayout (StackLayout, Grid, ListView and etc.)
2. Add "x:Reference" for your Command binding inside the StackLayout
3. The command is excluded.

Like:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="WhateverParent">
    <StackLayout x:DataType="model:Light">
        <Button ... Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ToggleLight, Source={x:Reference WhateverParent}}" />
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you! I modified it a little so I can send my Object to my ViewModel:
`<Button Text="{Binding Enabled}" Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:LightsViewModel}}, Path=ToggleLight}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>`